# I am having an issue while running a program called Spotx which is to Block ads in Spotify

Tags: github, command-prompt, spotify

I am running a program called [Spotx](https://github.com/amd64fox/SpotX)to block ads while listening music on Spotify But its showing a Error Which is like this in Command prompt

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At line:1 char:93
+ ... 2}; "& { $((Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing 'https://raw.githubuse ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

This is not the the first time I am running this program I had tried this once and it was successful but recently I deleted Spotify and now I need to do it again but it's not working
Also, after installing this program I was not able to use Spotify web player in any website and my internet had became slow only in my pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: **I DO NOT promote or encourage any illegal activities; I am answering this question for educational purposes only.**

For Indian users, the raw content of the GitHub file is blocked.
News link: https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/gadgets-news/github-content-domain-blocked-for-these-indian-users-reports/articleshow/96687992.cms

Using any VPN, you can solve this error and enjoy your music ad-free on Spotify.